# JSTree add a new parent or sub child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

we are trying to add a new node using below details :

Here is how my jstree got created :

```
$('#m_tree_3').jstree({
                      'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
                      'core': {
                              "themes" : {
                                      "responsive": true
                              },       
                              'data': $('#m_tree_3').data('treedata'). //--------------->>>>this is a tag where i have my data, i am taking data from here
                      },
                      "types" : {
                              "default" : {
                                      "icon" : "fa fa-folder m--font-warning"
                              },
                              "file" : {
                                      "icon" : "fa fa-file   m--font-warning"
                              }
                      },
              });


$('#m_tree_3').jstree().create_node([null, "New Node", "first", function(){ 
            alert("Dene");
        }, true]);
```

Here is how it looks in my HTML:

```
<div id="m_tree_3" class="" data-treedata="{{ json_encode($categories) }}"></div>
<div class="output_value"></div>
```

I am trying but the node is not getting created.

Comment: Can a node be created without a parent?

Comment: Yes, parent node can also be created. @fingeron

Comment: Do you have `check_callback` set to `true`?

Comment: @fingeron where i can check that? Because i dont think i have it enabled. I am creating tree from a different function.

Comment: I have just updated the code to give you a more visual appereance

Comment: Add this:  `'core' : {
                        'check_callback': true }`

Comment: Ok checking...give me moment

Comment: Nothing happened!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162824/discussion-between-fingeron-and-user3201500).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important things to notice here,

One is that the `[` and `]` characters in the jsTree [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=create_node(%5Bpar,%20node,%20pos,%20callback,%20is_loaded%5D) are a little bit misleading. They are not describing an array literal, only that all the inputs are **optional**.

Further more, it is important to not forget the `check_callback` parameter in the jsTree `core` settigns.

So a fixed code would be:

```
$('#m_tree_3').jstree({
     'plugins': ["wholerow", "checkbox", "types"],
     'core': {
          "check_callback": true
          "themes" : {
              "responsive": true
           },       
           'data': $('#m_tree_3').data('treedata').
     },
     "types" : {
           "default" : {
               "icon" : "fa fa-folder m--font-warning"
           },
           "file" : {
              "icon" : "fa fa-file   m--font-warning"
           }
     },  
});
```

And for appending the additional parent node:

```
$("#m_tree_3").jstree('create_node', null , {"text":"GO somewhere","slug":"hhhhhhhhh","id":2387}, 'last', function() { 
     alert("added"); 
});
```